# replacing item in dictionary and formating

Tags: python

hello I am new to python and have a question. Is it possible to format a dictionary like you can a list.

my code out out puts the items in a like this:

```
1294919 : (Person(1294919, 'Russel', 97.00, 1.90, 24, 0), 31022)
```

I want it do be like this:

```
1294919 : Person(1294919, 'Russel', 97.00, 1.90, 24, 31022)
```

so the number outside the bracket should be where the 0 is.

code:

```
{1665845: Person(1665845, 'Rurick', 101.00, 1.98, 75, 0), 1294919: Person(1294919, 'Russel', 97.00, 1.90, 24, 0)}

lines = [['1665845', '2001-01-06', '28,448,615,27,705'], ['1665845', '2001-01-10', '218,37,356,621,466,319,147,774,231,167,399,150,417,34,3'], ['1294919', '2001-01-04', '639,118,328,413,222,491,738,389,11,372,183,650,281,643,26,398,685,171'], ['1294919', '2001-01-10', '314,611,485,208,515,240,586,511,713,58,28,392,140,529,353,489,375,412,596'], ['1665845', '2001-01-04', '670,665,681,184,22,752,390,523,507,171,467,19,296,720,58,230,721,686'], ['1665845', '2001-01-02', '432,210,732,204,771,555,448,82,343'], ['1294919', '2001-01-06', '113,225,564,554,392,544,313'], ['1294919', '2001-01-05', '437,219,239,545,588,303,477,384,87,254,429,635,188,372,572,712,383'], ['1294919', '2001-01-03', '771,373'], ['1294919', '2001-01-08', '650,679,492,524,202,689,224,268,195,455,400,235,518,505']]

from collections import defaultdict
d_dict = defaultdict(int)
for k,_, v in lines:
    d_dict[int(k)]+=sum(int(i) for i in v.split(','))

for k in people:


    people[k] = people[k], d_dict[k]
```

Person class:

```
class Person:

def __init__(self, id_num, name, weight, height, age):                

    self.id_num = id_num
    self.name = name      
    self.weight = weight
    self.height = height
    self.age = age
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is not very clear. however, if I got understood what you wanted, it depends a lot on the `Person` class your'e using. seems like you need to update it \ create a new instance.
the thing is that on your last like you are creating a **tuple** and not a `Person`, what you need to do should look like this:

```
for k in people:
    person = people[k]
    new_person = Person(person.id_num, person.name, person.weight, person.height, person.age, d_dict[k])
    people[k] = new_person
```

Comment: I added the class definition to OP, you are right im having trouble when I do that one. it gives me 'missing 3 required positional arguments: 'weight', 'height', and 'age'.

Comment: your `Person` class does not have a way to store that last number. I think you need to review to purpose of that class and rewrite it. (perhaps, add another member to it.